# Starting unwanted Services in Kotlin Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

I have a simple app that opens a service inside that service it repeats a function every 3 seconds the function should get a list of SMS that should be sent and start sending them. app works normally for hours then starts to send duplicate SMS like first sends 2 then 3 ... and my guess is that more than one service starts after a while but I'm not sure please help me with this code
this is how I start the service:

```
startService(Intent(this, BckService::class.java))
```

this is my service:

```
class BckService : Service() {
override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val apiService = RestApiService()
    val smsManager: SmsManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        smsManager = this.getSystemService(SmsManager::class.java)

    } else {
        smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
    }

    var smsId = 0
    startUpdates {
        apiService.getSmsList {
            var text = ""
            var phone = ""
            for (i in it) {
                if ((i.text == text && i.phone == phone)||i.id == smsId){
                    continue
                }
                text = i.text
                phone = i.phone
                val parts = smsManager.divideMessage(i.text)
                smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(i.phone,null,parts,null,null)
                apiService.smsSent(i.id)
                smsId = i.id
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
}
fun startUpdates(getData: () -> Unit) {
    job = scope.launch {
        while (true) {
            getData() 
            delay(3000)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is for problems/issues with the Android Studio product. This question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't ever stop your background `Thread`. Your `Service` can be stopped by Android (for all kinds of reasons) and this will not necessarily kill your background `Thread`. You should add code in `onDestroy()` of the `Service` that stops the background `Thread`.

Also, be aware that every time something calls `startService()` to start your `Service`, `onStartCommand()` will be called, and you will start another background `Thread`. So if you expect only 1 background `Thread` to be running at any given time, you need to keep track of that `Thread` and make sure that you don't start one if there is already one running.

---

You get returned a `Job` when you do this in `startUpdates()`:

```
job = scope.launch { ...
```

`job` is a reference to a `Job` and you should save that in your `Service` (it isn't clear from your code where the variable `job` is declared).

Implement `onDestroy()` in your `Service` and in that method you should do something like this:

```
job?.cancel()
job = null // clear any reference to a running Job
```

This will cancel the `Job` that is running your infinite loop.

Also, in `onStartCommand()`, you should cancel any `Job` that is already running before starting another infinite loop, using something like this:

```
job?.cancel()
job = null
```

Comment: how can i keep track of that thread an example please